# trying to import PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm not sure why but I always have an issue with importing PIL. No matter how I try to import it, it just never seems to work. I have tried to install it or update it. I have even tried with Pillow but still nothing. any help is greatly appreciated as it's something so little but so annoying. I am using python 3.10 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mp8t.png)

Comment: Please share the error logs as text in your post, not an image.

Comment: Did you get any information on `Pillow` module by running `python -m PIL` in the command line window? Make sure the Python used in PyCharm is the same as the one used in the command line window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIL is deprecated, it's a very old library. Its current maintained fork can be installed via `pip install Pillow`.

Comment: I have tried this also and it successfully installed but I still can't import??

Comment: Since Pillow is a fork of PIL, you need to import it with the old name but pip install it with the new one. Try ```import PIL```